# How to create an optional yes / no radiobutton in your viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Say I have long form, with many different optional values a user can enter.

One of these optional values is a boolean. Depending on the user input, I need to do the following in my database:

- If "yes", then add "1" in the database
- If "no", then add "0" in the database
- If non is entered, add "null" in the database

However, the most normal viewmodel / razor code I could find is the following:

```
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FurnitureIsIncluded)
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.FurnitureIsIncluded, true) Ja
```

Here my value would be false, as the default value of a boolean.

What is the way to fix this in MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a nullable bool for `FurnitureIsIncluded` in your view model

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.FurnitureIsIncluded, "true")<span>Yes</span>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.FurnitureIsIncluded, "false")<span>No</span>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.FurnitureIsIncluded, "", Model.FurnitureIsIncluded.HasValue ? null : new { @checked = "checked" })<span>Cant decide</span>
```

This will then post back `true` or `false` or `null` based on the selection. You would then need need to test for true/false to save the value as "1" or "0"

Comment: Lars, just realized that if initial value of `FurnitureIsIncluded` is null, the 3rd option will not be selected by default (which it should be). Refer updated code to fix this (added 3rd parameter with conditional check to set `checked="checked")